# Unwanted horizontal overflow when using padding top

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  padding-top: 20vh;
}

.content {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The problem is fairly simple. When I add padding-top to the .body div, there is a horizontal overflow. I would like to know why does the y-axis padding affect the x-axis width.

I know I can get rid of it using overflow-x: hidden, but it's a dirty solution.

Comment: Because a scroll bar is generated?

Comment: Sidenote: don't use a div with a `body` class or a `content` class. HTML has plenty of appropriate elements you should be using, like `<main>` and `<section>`. A `<div>` is your last resort. With that said, what are you trying to actually do? Because using a width or height with `calc` is almost certainly the solution you _actually_ want, not something involving padding.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is the scrollbar is the problem.
I want to use padding to leave some space for a navbar which placing is absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a percentage value:

```css
.body {
  width: 100%; /* Percentage-based (full width of <body>) */
}
```

> #### *More About VW and VH*
>
> *Viewport units represent a percentage of the current browser viewport (current browser size). While similar to % units, **there is a difference.** Viewport units are calculated as a percentage of the browser's current viewport size. **Percentage units on the other hand are calculated as a percentage of the parent element**, which may be different than the viewport size.*

Reference: [What’s The Difference Between PX, EM, REM, %, VW, and VH?](https://elementor.com/help/whats-the-difference-between-px-em-rem-vw-and-vh/#:%7E:text=While%20similar%20to,the%20viewport%20size.)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  width: 100%; /* Percentage-based (full width of <body>) */
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  padding-top: 20vh;
}

.content {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It did work, but I do not understand why. Do you have an explanations ?

Comment: @JohnLeRouge I added a statement to my post that explains that the child's container size is elative to the parent (when using percentages).

Comment: Thanks a lot about that

Comment: @JohnLeRouge actually you don't need to set any width because by default the element is a block element that will take all the space

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this issue is quite simple & the culprit is y-axis scrollbar.

Lets first undertands how viewports works . Viewport units looks at the window rather than the content on the page. So when you were trying to render a width of 50vw it actally rendered the viewport not including the scrollbar width in it . The reason you see scrollbar in x-axis is due this reason. In simple words the scrollbar width is not included ( y-axis one ) when calculating the width of the element hence there's a overflow issue.

To bypass this behaviour you can use the overflow overlay. Which makes scrollbar floats over the content ( overlays y-axis scrollbar )

```css
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      div {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .body {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: black;

        /** the bug fix **/
        overflow: overlay; 
      }

      .content {
        width: 50vw;
        height: 1000px;
        background-color: yellow;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="body">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
```

For understanding overflow overlay checkout this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: Hi @Mr. Polywhirl   it's all about the overflows !

Comment: The `overlay` value hides content, is legacy, and is not supported by Safari.

Comment: @Darryl Noakes Yupp totally agreed ! But I guess OP just wanted to know the reason for overflow,  to explain and demonstrate I used overlay on purpose . Also using % is the best way to go but understanding why is what drove me to write the answer !

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set up the page with a header (as your comment suggests) then why not use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to guide you, and semantic elements.

Set the body as a flex column element. Add a `header` element to that at `20vh`, and then add a `main` element with your content.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 20vh;
}

main {
  background-color: black;
  height: 1000px;
}

.content {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main class="body">
    <section class="content"></section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

why adding padding to the .body div causes a horizontal overflow is because of the default behavior of the CSS box-sizing property

> You can try this css

```html
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    div {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .body {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: black;
        padding-top: 20vh;
    }

    .content {
        width: calc(50vw - 20vh); /* Subtracting the padding value from the width */
        height: 1000px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: That does not work.